# How Do I Make HTML Comment Script Use Hash Fragment ID In URL

Tags: javascript, html, comments, window.location, fragment-identifier

I am using a comment box on my blogs from htmlcommentbox.com, and the service allows me to ignore query strings in my urls, but how do I recognize fragment IDs after the hash? Is there a way for me to edit the code given to me with window.location...?

**UPDATE:** Basically, I use Blogger and wanted to delete the ?m=1 query string when there's a mobile request, and I found a way to remove the query string but keep the hash.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var cleanUri = location.protocol + &#39;//&#39; + location.host + location.pathname + location.hash;
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, cleanUri);
  </script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Minor peeve: `#` is called a hash. `#word` is a hashtag (`word` being the "tag" in this example)

Comment: haha my bad....